# How do I give access to execute packages and select from table for another schema

Tags: permissions, oracle

I have a schema called SCHEMA1 with packages and tables that needs to be accessed by user SCHEMA2.

I want SCHEMA2 to have access for executing packages and look at source code. Also I would like to give SELECT access to all tables for SCHEMA2.

How can I do that? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I answered a very [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/865586/oracle-how-to-grant-to-a-user-the-rights-to-another-users-objects) on stackoverflow.

Basically, it's this:

```
BEGIN
  FOR Rec IN (SELECT object_name, object_type FROM all_objects WHERE owner='SCHEMA1' AND object_type IN ('TABLE','VIEW','PROCEDURE','FUNCTION','PACKAGE')) LOOP
    IF Rec.object_type IN ('TABLE','VIEW') THEN
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'GRANT SELECT ON SCHEMA1.'||Rec.object_name||' TO SCHEMA2';
    ELSIF Rec.object_type IN ('PROCEDURE','FUNCTION','PACKAGE') THEN
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'GRANT EXECUTE ON SCHEMA1.'||Rec.object_name||' TO SCHEMA2';
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: +1 for an excellent script.  I would prefer, though, that the script grant the privileges to a role and that this role gets granted to Schema2.  Otherwise, administration gets quite hairy because there will inevitably be multiple users that will need the same set of permissions.

Comment: I try to run it from Toad and I get errors, any idea why? (I'm such a lousy DBA)

Comment: @Phillipe: What kind of errors?  @Justin: Of course, roles are superior when there's any chance that multiple users will become involved. The problem is that administration is going to be hairy anyway - any time an object is created in schema1, schema2 will have to be granted access. It would be nice to be able to grant all on a schema to a user, rather than on an object by object basis.

Comment: Error at line 1
ORA-06550: line 2, column 157:
PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
ORA-06550: line 2, column 14:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
ORA-06550: line 4, column 82:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ";" when expecting one of the following:

   loop

Comment: There was a missing right paren on the FOR statement. Try it now.

Comment: Thank you it worked! I had to remove 'VIEW' from statement because some views were depending on objects in other schemas I didn't want to give access to. Thanks again!

Comment: I'm also giving you points on SO for same question/answer.

Comment: Thanks, glad it works for you - sorry about the typo, clearly not tested before posting final answer!